# How to make .wav file from MFCC sequence

Tags: python, audio, deep-learning, librosa, mfcc

I want to know how to make .wav file from MFCC sequence.

```py
import librosa
import soundfile as sf

a,sr = librosa.load(filename)# filename is *.wav
y = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=a, sr=sr)#sr is 22050
```

I want to do the reverse of the above code.
I tried using "librosa.feature.inverse.mel_to_audio"

```
M=librosa.feature.inverse.mel_to_audio(y, sr=22050, n_fft=2048)
sf.write('out.wav', M, 22050, 'PCM_24')
```

I ran above code but I could't restore the audio.
Is the argument wrong, or is the method usage wrong?
I need to know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't make it"? What was the issue? Can you paste the code you used?

Comment: The last line, `sr.write('out.wav',M,22050,'PCM_24')`, would give you an error, so I am guessing it's not how it looked originally. Can you put the right one, making sure the code runs and produces the mentioned issue? You also haven't described the issues. If that's difficult, consider linking the original WAV and the result.

Answer (score 1):

you need use other method for restoring audio from mfcc and use sr = None in order to sample rate would be from your audio and not default value = 22050

```
import soundfile as sf
a,sr = librosa.load('0.wav', sr=None)
y = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=a,sr=sr)

M=librosa.feature.inverse.mfcc_to_audio(y, sr=sr, n_fft=2048)
sf.write('out.wav', M, 22050, 'PCM_24')
```

Answer (score 0):

for saving wav files you can use soundfile package

```
import soundfile as sf  
  
output = '/kaggle/working/output.wav'  
sf.write(output, y_reconstructed, sr)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).